# How to use the Debian scons-doc package

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I installed the scons-doc package for my Mint Debian, but then I don't know how to access the documentation. I have tried to google search, but did not find any useful information. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out: the scons-doc package is installed at

```
/usr/share/doc/scons-doc
```

In this directory, there are sub directories: html, PDF, and PS. In these directories, I found the documentation in their respective formats.